# Short-term forecast of Europe by using synoptic charts

Tags: meteorology, wind, clouds, weather-forecasting, rainfall

I should make a **short-term forecast** of Europe by using synoptic charts. I'm finding it really hard so I'd be glad if you help me.

[image]
[image]
[image]

### 'В' means high atmospheric pressure

I'm trying to figure out the legend of the chart, and I hope I did it right:

- White: wind
- Blue: rainfall
- Orange: clouds

I'd appreciate it if you give me some hints. Thank you!

Comment: Listing the site from where you obtained the pictures would be helpful. The colors **might be** rain intensity: white being light rain or showers, blue heavier or steady rain, orange **might be** very intense rain. The site should have information regarding its color scheme (legend).

Comment: @NikolDimitrova why do you think blue is rainfall ? It can be wind as well. Normally these plots are separate i,e, one for wind one for rainfall and one for clouds. So as Fred says from which site did you download this ?

Comment: I got these pictures from my  book. It isn't mentioned where they obtained the pictures.

Comment: I think you are right. The colours might be rain intensity because there are other pictures showing atmospheric pressure and wind.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Can you tell us the name of the book ? :)

Comment: It's my student's book in Bulgaria. I think you can't have it. I

Comment: How do I begin? What to include?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova well if you want us to help you then you need to give us more details otherwise it will be like shooting in the dark

Comment: @gansub, what details do you need?

Comment: Using these charts (regions with rainfalls) I should determine how the situation of the atmosphere **changes in 24 hours** (for **Europe**) - **cloud, temperatures, rainfalls, atmospheric pressure**. What are the **weather patterns (tendencies)** based on the charts?

Comment: @gansub, added all charts.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova. Ok you provided the details. Now give us time to think over this. If I know the answer I will write it down. It will take time.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova So you have in those charts a classical frontal system with cold air masses and warm air masses colliding over western Europe. On the England France atmospheric "border". Presuming the second chart is temperature blue air masses represent cooler air and green and orange warmer air masses. These come from north and south respectively.  Are you aware of frontal systems and baroclinicity ?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova There is imminent rain or snow expected in the next few hours over England and France.  Final chart is of surface pressure. It tells one where the surface low will form and develop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100631/discussion-between-gansub-and-nikol-dimitrova).